# Using Shell CMD.exe start with Web Links

Tags: vb.net, shell

I want to start an application through my VB program by using Shell("CMD.exe /C start, but it does not seem to work with big web links.

For example:

```
endereco = "https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=6ab38ad8310d6f75&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport=yes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1417990333&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=483CE9BE39FE3DF05F63765809AEC7BA615017FF.DCC9F4C22EAD12EF9EDF1E00C24CD2A886A56E8&key=lh1"
Shell("CMD.exe /C start ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MPC-HC\mpc-hc.exe ", endereco)
```

This does not seem to work, it gives an error about being converted to short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Process.Start(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\MPC-HC\mpc-hc.exe", endereco)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse endereco as a Microsoft.VisualBasic.AppWinStyle

Try this instead

```
        Dim endereco As String = "https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=6ab38ad8310d6f75&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport=yes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1417990333&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=483CE9BE39FE3DF05F63765809AEC7BA615017FF.DCC9F4C22EAD12EF9EDF1E00C24CD2A886A56E8&key=lh1"
        Shell("CMD.exe /C start ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MPC-HC\mpc-hc.exe"" """ & endereco & """")
```